# FLutter : The method '[]' was called on null when iterating list

Tags: flutter

This is the source code I have till now. Can you tell me what is wrong and why I am getting this error?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The error is:

error in Data[0] it show Flutter : The method '[]' was called on null when iterating list import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class MyGetHttpDataState extends State<MyGetHttpData> { 

    final String url = "*******";
    List data, a; int index; // Function to get the JSON data 

    Future<String> getJSONData() async {
        var response = await http.get(url);
        print(response.body);
        setState(() {
           json.decode(response.body);
           data = dataConvertedToJSON['data']; index = 0;
        });
        return "Successfull";
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp( 
          home: new Scaffold( 
            appBar: new AppBar( title: new Text('List Test'), ), 
            body: new Center( 
              child: Column( 
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                children: <Widget>[
                  for (var name in data[0]['INCI']) Text(name)
                ], ), ), )); 
    } 

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      this.getJSONData(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run code it show error for 1 sec then give me result

Comment: what i can if i can't do that ?

Comment: what error is showing?

Comment: The method '[]' was called on null. 
if i remove : for (var name in data[0]['INCI']) Text(name) no more error there

Comment: What do you want? to print all the values in INCI or something else?

Comment: no solution ???

Comment: Working on that, will post an answer in a while

Comment: i just added if (data!=null) and it fixed it thx bro

Comment: Great. Check the below answer as well bro.

Comment: i will try it thx alot

Comment: Marked that accepted if it helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code to this!

```
Future<String> getJSONData() async {
    var response = await http.get(url);
    setState(() {
       var dataConvertedToJSON = json.decode(response.body);
       data = dataConvertedToJSON['data'];
       data = data[0]['INCI'];
    });
    return "Successfull";
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp( 
      home: new Scaffold( 
        appBar: new AppBar( title: new Text('List Test'), ), 
        body: new Center( 
          child: data != null ? Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
            children: <Widget>[
              for (var name in data) Text(name)
            ], 
          ) : new CircularProgressIndicator(), 
        ), 
      )
    ); 
}
```

Comment: but when i do another search and no result is found it gives me the last result and iwant to show ' not found'

Comment: Just change `new CircularProgressIndicator(),`  to  `new Text("Not Found")`

Comment: bro srry if i disturb again
but when i use  AlertDialog it give me smth like this black screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2aHA.png

Comment: when and where you are using this?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ZER40Jom
i m using  custom dialog  giffy
import 'package:giffy_dialog/giffy_dialog.dart';

Comment: hey again , dialog alert keep giving me  black screen background after i fetch result into her , sometimes it  crash , sometime i need to click ok or cancel button multiple times to close it

Comment: Can you ask different question for this, it seems like different problem you are facing